# Delete a property from a returned mongoose document instance. MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Here is the situation, I have created a jwt token which depends upon the user document, but the problem is that for security purposes I don't want to include the password field in the `user` object that is passed into my `encode` function.

```
router.post('/admin/login', (req, res, next)=>{
  passport.authenticate('local-login', (err, user, info)=> {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }else if (!user) {
      return res.json(info)

    }else {
      user.toObject();
      delete user.password;
      console.log(`User is ${user}`);
      let token = encode(user, 'inav');
      return res.send(token)
    }

  })(req, res, next);
})
```

I've tried this, but this isn't working. The `user` still contains the password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local is the passport strategy you are using, it returns a mongoose model. You must convert it to a plain object to be able to delete password property. toObject returns an object which must be stored in a variable.

```
const userObj = user.toObject();
delete userObj.password;
console.log(`User is ${userObj}`);
const token = encode(userObj, 'inav');
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject

Comment: Interesting that earlier I had tried this and it didn't work. Thank you for your answer.